# How can i get the data grid column entries filled up inside the web forms from database?

Tags: c#, webforms

I am using a data grid that take an input by clinking a combo box applied on the column of a data grid .So by clicking we can get the grid entries filled from data base tables so that i can edit it, add entries and also delete those entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this line of code  to display that values

datagridview.Rows[1].Cells[1].Text